# Optimize stocks for the investment

Tags: optimization

I don't know the problem name exactly, but it should be related to stock investment strategy. I have budget `A = 30` Consider this list: `myList = [[10,15], [11,13], [9,10]]` for each element the first is expected return value, and second is the price.

Buying the first and second items maximize the return `[10,15], [11,13]` as `13 + 15 < 30` and return value is `21`.

I have prioritize them based on value per price:

```
-------------
9,  10,  0.9
11, 13, 0.846
10, 15, 0.666
-------------
```

I Try to pick elements until my budget cannot afford element. Of course, this is not the right answer since it return `[9,10], [11,13]` and value `20`.

I would appreciate any hint or link or even problem name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have posed the knapsack problem:

> The knapsack problem or rucksack problem is a problem in combinatorial
>   optimization: Given a set of items, each with a weight and a value,
>   determine the number of each item to include in a collection so that
>   the total weight is less than or equal to a given limit and the total
>   value is as large as possible. It derives its name from the problem
>   faced by someone who is constrained by a fixed-size knapsack and must
>   fill it with the most valuable items.

The problem is essentially difficult (in a well defined technical sense). There 
 are clever computer programs that find the answer, but for long lists they are not as fast as you'd hope.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Thanks, that's a good hint, it is exactly knapsack problem.